# How do I compute the translation and rotation velocities of a robot

Tags: kinematics, two-wheeled

I am stuck at computing the translation and rotation of a robot moving onto an ellipse given by:

$$
p(t) =(m) + \cos(t)∗a + \sin(t)*b
$$

where m = center of ellipse and the two axes a (horizontal) and b (vertical).

At the moment I am using derivation $p'(t)$ for calculating the translation, like

$$
p'(t)_x = -\sin(t)*a \\
p'(t)_y = \cos(t)*b
$$

$$
p'(t) = \sqrt{p'(t)_x^2 + p'(t)_y^2}
$$

and rotation velocity, with

$$
p''(t)_x = -\cos(t)*a \\
p''(t)_y = -\sin(t)*b
$$

$$
p''(t) = \frac{p'(t)_x p''(t)_y - p''(t)_x p'(t)_y}{ (p'(t)_x)^2 + (p'(t)_y)^2} $$

(see formula)

However, the robot is just moving in strange curls instead of an ellipse.
If anyone needs the full code just say so.

$$
\omega = \dot{\phi} = \frac{\dot{d_x}\ddot{d_y} - \ddot{d_x}\dot{d_y}}{\dot{d_x}^2+\dot{d_y}^2}
$$

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, mojado. I'm not sure where you're getting these equations from, so please *edit your question* to include the source that you're using for what you've given. To be clear, I'm worried for you that you're basing your work on the [parametric equations for an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_representation), which take a similar $a*\cos(t)$, $b*\sin(t)$ form. In those equations, though, $t$ is **not time**, it's the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly), so you can't use a derivative of $\sin(t)$, for example, as speed.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include some more background, such as what you're trying to do with your calculations. It's not clear if you're trying to calculate speeds to get a robot to move along an elliptical path, or if you're trying to calculate the path to do something like inverse kinematics, etc. A diagram would help a lot, to show us what your definitions and conventions are, how you've formulated your equations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Chuck said you are using the parametric form of the ellipse

$p(t) = (m) + cos(t)*a + sin(t)*b$  the $t$ doesn't represent the time but the eccentric anomaly. But from this equation you can create a matrix for $t\epsilon [0,2\pi]$ and calculate the points on the eclipse from the equations

$ x = a*cos(t) $ , $ y = b*sin(t) $ then you have $(x,y)$ points and by setting a specific time that you want to go from one point to another you can find the velocities ${\Delta x\over \Delta t} , {\Delta x\over \Delta t} $. Not the best way to do it, but it is something.